# Selecting rows in a Pandas DataFrame based on conditions of the index values

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following multi-index DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index0':[0,1,2,3,4,5],'Index1':[100,200,300,400,500,600],'A':[5,2,5,8,1,2]})
```

[image: example DataFrame]

Now I want to select all the rows where Index1 is less than 400. 
Everybody knows how that works if Index1 was a regular column:

```
df[df['Index1'] < 400]
```

So one method would be to `reset_index`, perform the selection, then set the index again. This seems quite redundant.

My question is: Is there a way to do this directly? And how to do this when the DataFrame has a row multiindex?

Comment: Oops. Forgot `df.set_index(['Index0','Index1'])` in the code.

Comment: Ahem, that should have been `df.set_index(['Index0','Index1'],inplace=True)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simpliest here is use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query('Index1 < 400')
print (df1)
               A
Index0 Index1   
0      100     5
1      200     2
2      300     5
```

Or [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for select level of `MultiIndex` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values('Index1') < 400]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.index.get_level_values('Index1'))
Int64Index([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600], dtype='int64', name='Index1')
```

---

If levels have no names select by positions, for query use special keyword `ilevel_` with position:

```
df.index.names = [None, None]
print (df)
       A
0 100  5
1 200  2
2 300  5
3 400  8
4 500  1
5 600  2

df1 = df.query('ilevel_1 < 400')

df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values(1) < 400]
print (df1)
       A
0 100  5
1 200  2
2 300  5
```

Comment: Many thanks @jezrael for prompt and complete answer. I can see now why `query` is convenient. I should have known the second method.